# Old Norse Riddle!

Tags: riddle

An old Norse riddle, quite an easy one when you think of it.

> A dragon with one wing and 24 legs, sheds its scales on the sand.

What is it?

Comment: Hello! Don't give the answer yet, take the tour (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how the site works and don't hesitate to check other posts

Comment: Sorry about this, I shall remember this for any future posts! Thank you for the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> A ship

A dragon with one wing and 24 legs, sheds its scales on the sand.

> The ship could be seen as a dragon with the sail as wing. The viking boats (it's a Norse riddle) had a sculpture on the bow which might be a dragon. It has 24 rowers, so the oars could be seen as legs.
>  As for the scales, I guess when the vikings disembark on the sand, they take with them their shields which on the boat were used to protect the sides of the ship so they look like dragon scales.

Comment: @Rubio Thanks for the edit. I couldn't find straight away the English word.

Comment: You are indeed correct!

Comment: @JamesDicken In this case you can mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @rhsquared ACKCHYUALLY marking the first and only answer as accepted will spoil the popularity of the riddle and prevent users to post their answers. Waiting a little more before accept could be a good idea to give visibility and chances to everyone (even if the answer was disclosed)

Comment: @Saeïdryl Good point. I didn't think of that.